# Gradle JavaExec StandardOutput to include Java command

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to add in the java command to the standardOutput stream on a JavaExec command in Gradle?

Ie

```
task importSitesDef(dependsOn: init, type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.x'
    classpath = configurations.runE
    standardOutput = new FileOutputStream(standardLog, true)
}
```

Will log the output but I want to see
java com.x -cp ... in the file too before the input.

This is due to using the same output stream/file for multiple tasks and its very hard to tell where the output from one task finished before another one starts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but all I did to get the Java command used was to get the output of the `JavaExec` `commandLine` method and join it's elements, like so:-

`commandLine.collect().join(' ')`

Then output it.